# VBA CODE CORRECTION

Tags: vba

I am using VBA for the first time. I started with a very basic code using Runga Kutta Method. I am not able to run it. Can I know where I am going wrong? Can you also post some solutions for this type of differential equation solvers?

```
Option Explicit

Dim K1 As Double
Dim K2 As Double
Dim K3 As Double
Dim K4 As Double

Dim y As Double
Dim x As Double
Dim dx As Double
Dim x0 As Integer
Dim y0 As Integer



Function f(x, y) As Double
   f = 0.5 * x - 0.5 * y
    End Function


Sub RK(x, y, dx)

Dim i As Integer
Dim ynew As Double
dx = 0.5
x0 = 0
y0 = 1
K1 = dx * f(x, y)
K2 = dx * f(x + dx / 2, y + K1 / 2)
K3 = dx * f(x + dx / 2, y + K2 / 2)
K4 = dx * f(x + dx, y + K3)
 RK = y + ((K1 + 2 * (K2 + K3 + K4)) / 6)


For i = 0 To 6
ynew = RK(x, y, dx)
x = x + dx
y = ynew
Next i

For j = 1 To 6
Call RK(x, y, dx, ynew)
ActiveCell.Offset(i - 1, 1).Value = x
ActiveCell.Offset(i - 1, 2).Value = y
x = x + dx
y = ynew
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the issue with the code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the `RK` procedure and give it the starting values of x, y and dx.
To do this from within the VBE (Visual Basic Editor) open the Immediate window.  If it's not visible press Ctrl+G and it should appear at the bottom of the VBE.

In the Immediate window type something like `RK 1, 3, 2` and the results will appear in the two columns to the right of the active cell and take up 6 rows.

If you want the procedure to execute on the press of a button, or when a value is updated you'll need to add an extra bit of code for that.

**Edit:**
Just noticed these lines - `RK = y + ((K1 + 2 * (K2 + K3 + K4)) / 6)` and `ynew = RK(x, y, dx)`.
The `RK` procedure won't return a value and you can't set it as a value either.
This link may help explain it:  http://what-when-how.com/excel-vba/vba-sub-and-function-procedures/